# How to fix bootstrap 3 footer to fix at bottom with all responsive view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

After a research and stack overflow's question and answer I failed and now need expert's view.
Please check my homepage view in small resolution the footer is not flushing to footer.

http://responsivedesignchecker.com/dev2d.com/projects/ihound/index.php

or http://responsivetest.com/dev2d.com/projects/ihound/index.php

I have tried with this, its not working in iPhone

```
.footerBottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    text-align: center !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height:60px;
}
```

Comment: There is a footer class by default in Bootstrap 3, check an example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

Answer (score 4):

Use the built in navbar-fixed-bottom class and don't forget to add the body padding:

**HTML:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
body { padding-bottom: 70px; }
```

For more details see: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar and go to the section marked: Fixed to bottom.

Comment: Simple, but the padding solved the problem of the footer covering page content.

Answer (score 1):

**It will work in desktop as well as mobile**
*Tested*

```
.footer {
bottom: 0;
margin: 0 auto !important;
text-align: center !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: 40px;
position: absolute; }
```